# Reverse the given String in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a situation to manipulate a given string which is separated by comma and reverse the given string.

**Input**: `hello,world,wow`

**Expected Output**: `wow,world,hello`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the solution to reverse the given string.

```js
let str = "hello,world,wow";
let temp = str.split(",");
let output = "";
// Index will starting from last element
let index = (temp.length - 1);
for(let k=0; k<temp.length; k++){
  if(k == (temp.length - 1)){
  // Last Element so no need of comma
  output += temp[index];
  }
  else {
  // Adding commas to the output
  output += temp[index]+",";
  }
  
  index--;
}
alert(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

First split the string by the comma. Then reverse the array. Then turn it back into a string.

```
let foo = 'hello,world,wow' // assign the string
foo = foo.split(',') // splits by comma
foo = foo.reverse() // reverses the array
foo = foo.join() // converts array back into a comma separated string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var initialString = "hello,world,wow"
var finalString = initialString.split(",").reverse().join(",");
console.log(finalString) // "wow,world,hello"
```